# How to stretch DataTable to full width in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datatable

I need `Datatable` to stretch to max width, but right now it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD2ou.png).

I've tried to use `ConstrainedBox`, but it didn't work out and showed me an error

```
 SingleChildScrollView _dataBody() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: DataTable(
            headingRowColor:
                MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Color(0xFF2F80ED)),
            headingTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            columns: [
              DataColumn(label: Text('ID')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Surname')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Birth date')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Algebra')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Chemistry')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Programing'))
            ],
            rows: _students
                .map((student) => DataRow(cells: [
                      DataCell(Text(student.id)),
                      DataCell(Text(student.firstName.toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(student.lastName.toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(student.birthDate.toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(student.algebra.toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(student.chemistry.toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(student.programing.toString()))
                    ]))
                .toList()),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this is the part where I implement my table:

```
Expanded(
          child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 110,
              child: Container(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: _dataBody(),
            )
          ],
        ))
```